# Retrieved data from JSON but can't Accessing Arraylist from JSONobject

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I'm very new in Android and Java Programming and currently developing my skill.

now, i faced a problem with accessing Arraylist from JSONresponse.

It's just i don't know how to initiate my Variable based on Json nested object, and access it without setting it to recylerview etc.

so this is the JSON

```
{"kode":1,
"pesan":"Anda Berhasil Login",
"data":[{"Id_Ortu":"1","NamaLengkapOrtu":"Alpiyan
Yamin"}]}
```

`ResponseModel` class

```
public class ResponseModel {
    private int kode;
    private String pesan,sql;
    private List<DataModel> data;

    public String getSql() {
        return sql;
    }

    public void setSql(String sql) {
        this.sql = sql;
    }

    public int getKode() {
        return kode;
    }

    public void setKode(int kode) {
        this.kode = kode;
    }

    public String getPesan() {
        return pesan;
    }

    public void setPesan(String pesan) {
        this.pesan = pesan;
    }

    public List<DataModel> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<DataModel> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

`ResponseModel` class

```
public class DataModel {

    private int Id_Perizinan, Id_Ortu;
   private String NamaLengkapSantri, NamaLengkapOrtu, Alasan_Izin, Tgl_Pengajuan,
            Durasi_Izin, Tgl_Kembali;

    public int getId_Perizinan() {
        return Id_Perizinan;
    }

    public void setId_Perizinan(int id_Perizinan) {
        Id_Perizinan = id_Perizinan;
    }

    public int getId_Ortu() {
        return Id_Ortu;
    }

    public void setId_Ortu(int id_Ortu) {
        Id_Ortu = id_Ortu;
    }

    public String getNamaLengkapSantri() {
        return NamaLengkapSantri;
    }

    public void setNamaLengkapSantri(String namaLengkapSantri) {
        NamaLengkapSantri = namaLengkapSantri;
    }

    public String getNamaLengkapOrtu() {
        return NamaLengkapOrtu;
    }

    public void setNamaLengkapOrtu(String namaLengkapOrtu) {
        NamaLengkapOrtu = namaLengkapOrtu;
    }

    public String getAlasan_Izin() {
        return Alasan_Izin;
    }

    public void setAlasan_Izin(String alasan_Izin) {
        Alasan_Izin = alasan_Izin;
    }

    public String getTgl_Pengajuan() {
        return Tgl_Pengajuan;
    }

    public void setTgl_Pengajuan(String tgl_Pengajuan) {
        Tgl_Pengajuan = tgl_Pengajuan;
    }

    public String getDurasi_Izin() {
        return Durasi_Izin;
    }

    public void setDurasi_Izin(String durasi_Izin) {
        Durasi_Izin = durasi_Izin;
    }

    public String getTgl_Kembali() {
        return Tgl_Kembali;
    }

    public void setTgl_Kembali(String tgl_Kembali) {
        Tgl_Kembali = tgl_Kembali;
    }
```

and this is how I try to retrieve the data

```
public void loginAplikasi(){

        APIRequestData apiRequestData = RetroServer.koneksiRetrofit().create(APIRequestData.class);
        Call<ResponseModel> loginApp = apiRequestData.ardLogin(username,password);

        loginApp.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseModel>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseModel> call, Response<ResponseModel> response) {
              
                int kode = response.body().getKode();
                String pesan = response.body().getPesan();
                listData = response.body().getData();
                int Id_Ortu = 0;
                String NamaLengkapOrtu;




                  alertDialog(NamaLengkapOrtu);




                    } else {
                        alertDialog(pesan);
                    }
                }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
               alertDialog(t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }
```

i successfully catched 'kode' and 'pesan' From JSON by using

```
 int kode = response.body().getKode();
 String pesan = response.body().getPesan();
```

i've declared a listData as new arraylist

```
 List<DataModel> listData = new ArrayList<>();
```

however, how can i access the value of

```
  listData = response.body().getData();
```

which contained *array* inside of **data**

so i can initiate variable ( NamaLengkapOrtu = listdata(arrayIndex) )

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your DataModel and ResponseModel?

Comment: @AkashBisht hello sir, posted below this answer

Comment: @AlldiAghlan what you want to achieve here?

Comment: I want to access the json Array value inside data @Ali Ahsan

Comment: @AliAhsan i want to access the value inside object "data" so i'm be able to initiate NamaLengkapOrtu = listData(value). how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with `DataModel` class.

```
public class DataModel {

    @SerializedName("Id_Ortu")
    @Expose
    private String idOrtu;
    @SerializedName("NamaLengkapOrtu")
    @Expose
    private String namaLengkapOrtu;
    
    public String getIdOrtu() {
    return idOrtu;
    }
    
    public void setIdOrtu(String idOrtu) {
    this.idOrtu = idOrtu;
    }
    
    public String getNamaLengkapOrtu() {
    return namaLengkapOrtu;
    }
    
    public void setNamaLengkapOrtu(String namaLengkapOrtu) {
    this.namaLengkapOrtu = namaLengkapOrtu;
    }

 }
```

Then you can access data as follows:

```
String namaLengkapOrtu = listdata.get(index).getNamaLengkapOrtu();
String idOrtu = listdata.get(index).getIdOrtu();
```

Comment: thank you for the advice,
may i know how to access the value on myActivity after changing the model class?
as for the example
i want to declare var NamaLengkapOrtu  = listData(value of index)

Comment: Hello, i received error upon accessing the data
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

this is how i access it
    int Id_Ortu = listData.get(0).getId_Ortu();
    String NamaLengkapOrtu = listData.get(1).getNamaLengkapOrtu();

Comment: Currently, listData size is only 1, so you can't use 1 for indexing. change `istData.get(1).getNamaLengkapOrtu();` to `istData.get(0).getNamaLengkapOrtu();`

Comment: finally! its done by adding serialized in datamodel. thank you so much Sir.

Comment: @AlldiAghlan `Serialized` is not necessary as long as your model class has members variables with the exact same name.

Answer (score 0):

As your JSON response is:

```json
{"kode":1,
"pesan":"Anda Berhasil Login",
"data":[{"Id_Ortu":"1","NamaLengkapOrtu":"Alpiyan
Yamin"}]}
```

Use the below annotation in your model class:

```
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
```

Here, "data" is the key you want to get from JSON.

Try to use this `ResponseModel` class:

```
 public class ResponseModel {
     private int kode;
     private String pesan,SQL;
     @SerializedName("data")
     @Expose     
     private List<DataModel> data;
 
     public String getSql() {
         return sql;
     }
 
     public void setSql(String sql) {
         this.sql = sql;
     }
 
     public int getKode() {
         return kode;
     }
 
     public void setKode(int kode) {
         this.kode = kode;
     }
 
     public String getPesan() {
         return pesan;
     }
 
     public void setPesan(String pesan) {
         this.pesan = pesan;
     }
 
     public List<DataModel> getData() {
         return data;
     }
 
     public void setData(List<DataModel> data) {
         this.data = data;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. May i know how do i access the jsom array and initiate it to my variable? After adding annotation

Comment: seeking for your answer.

Comment: You can initialize your variable like you were doing it..

Comment: my apologies, i think i've been confusing. i mean, i want to intialize my other variable based on listData index value, as for the example var NamaLengkapOrtu = listData(Value of Index). however it keeps getting me an error

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Did you get jsonArray in listData?

Comment: i tried using listdata.get(), but it says index is out of bound
i'm using the same method to load the json to recyclerview and everything is works fine. 

in this case i just want to access the listData value so i'm be able to store a couple information on shared pref